# Pass value from newcommand to siunitx

Tags: macros, luatex, siunitx, datatool

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.csv}
filename,date,pressure
blabla,2018-03-12,66
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\getfirstrowfromcol}[2]{%
\DTLsetseparator{,}%
\DTLifdbexists{mydb}{\DTLdeletedb{mydb}}{}%
\DTLloadrawdb{mydb}{#1}%
\DTLgetvalue{\myname}{mydb}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydb}{#2}}%
\myname%
}

\begin{document}
\SI{\getfirstrowfromcol{myfile.csv}{pressure}}{\bar}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with lualatex I always get an error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.18 \DeclareSIUnit
                  \A  {        \ampere }
```

What is the problem with my newcommand?

Answer (score 5):

Your `\getfirstrowfromcol` command is not expandable. I suggest to do it a different way.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.csv}
filename,date,pressure
blabla,2018-03-12,66
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newcommand{\SIfromDB}[4][]{%
  \begingroup
  \DTLsetseparator{,}%
  \DTLifdbexists{mydb}{\DTLdeletedb{mydb}}{}%
  \DTLloadrawdb{mydb}{#2}%
  \DTLgetvalue{\myname}{mydb}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydb}{#3}}%
  \SI[#1]{\myname}{#4}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\SIfromDB{myfile.csv}{pressure}{\bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also call

```
\SIfromDB[<options>]{myfile.csv}{pressure}{\bar}
```

in case you need to pass some `\SI` options. Just by way of example, if you change the pressure entry to `111.111`, the call

```
\SIfromDB[output-decimal-marker={,}]{myfile.csv}{pressure}{\bar}
```

would print

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But I would prefer to have my command `\getfirstrowfromcol` separate to use it in other contexts not only in combination with siunitx

Comment: @Reza Nobody prevents you from defining it. But in that context you cannot use it.

Comment: So there's no chance of expanding it before forwarding the result to another macro?

Comment: @Reza It depends on the macro you want to pass the result to: in order to apply its number formatting features, `\SI` needs that the argument is fully expandable.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro `\getfirstrowfromcol` (re)defines and delivers the macro-token `\myname`.

How about providing an optional argument in the definition of `\getfirstrowfromcol`  for providing a macro-token whose first non-optional argument will be the token `\myname` ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.csv}
filename,date,pressure
blabla,2018-03-12,66
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getfirstrowfromcol}[3][\@firstofone]{%
  \DTLsetseparator{,}%
  \DTLifdbexists{mydb}{\DTLdeletedb{mydb}}{}%
  \DTLloadrawdb{mydb}{#2}%
  \DTLgetvalue{\myname}{mydb}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydb}{#3}}%
  #1{\myname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\getfirstrowfromcol{myfile.csv}{pressure} /
\getfirstrowfromcol[\texttt]{myfile.csv}{pressure} /
\getfirstrowfromcol[\SI]{myfile.csv}{pressure}{\bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(In case `\myname` is not to be the first argument of the macro-token provided in the optional argument, but the n-th-argument, provide the preceding (n-1) arguments within the optional argument also.

Be aware in this context that when nesting optional arguments within optional arguments, you need to nest entire optional arguments in curly braces. Sloppily speaking: These curly braces help outer optional arguments not to erroneously take closing square brackets of inner optional arguments for their own closing square brackets. These curly braces will be stripped by the mechanism that processes optional arguments.

I.e.,

```
\macroA[{%<-curly braces surround macroA's optional argument.
  \macroB[macroB's optional argument]{macroB's mandatory argument}%
}]{macroA's mandatory argument}
```

)

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the solution! I think with `xparse` the nesting of arguments is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the problem by using `parse-numbers=false`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.csv}
filename,date,pressure
blabla,2018-03-12,66
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\getfirstrowfromcol}[2]{%
\DTLsetseparator{,}%
\DTLifdbexists{mydb}{\DTLdeletedb{mydb}}{}%
\DTLloadrawdb{mydb}{#1}%
\DTLgetvalue{\myname}{mydb}{1}{\dtlcolumnindex{mydb}{#2}}%
\myname%
}

\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\getfirstrowfromcol{myfile.csv}{pressure}}{\bar}

\getfirstrowfromcol{myfile.csv}{pressure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This disables all number formatting options.

Comment: Seems to work for my desires, although only a workaround

Comment: @Reza You'll loose many potential features of siunitx, but if you don't need them, this is really a simple workaround

Answer (score 1):

By using lualatex an expandable macro is possible:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.csv}
filename,date,pressure
blabla,2018-03-12,66
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\getfirstrowfromcol}[2]{%
  \directlua{
    require("lualibs.lua")
    local splitter = utilities.parsers.csvsplitter()
    f = io.open("#1", 'r')
    s = f:read('*a')
    f.close()
    local list = splitter(s)
    local header = list[1]
    local body = list[2]
    for colidx, colname in pairs(header) do
      if colname == "#2" then
        tex.print(body[colidx])
        break
      end
    end
  }
}

\begin{document}
\getfirstrowfromcol{myfile.csv}{pressure} /
\texttt{\getfirstrowfromcol{myfile.csv}{pressure}} /
\SI{\getfirstrowfromcol{myfile.csv}{pressure}}{\bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]